# Changing to a dynamic slider

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to change the following codes so that it will change in to a dynamic slider.. 
Can anyone please tell how to edit the below codes to get a dynamic slider?? I cant view suggestions.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    color: #515151;
}
img {
     width: 40%;
    }

.carousel-inner {
      background-color: #C1E0FF;
}

.carousel-caption {
      font-size: 2em;
      right: 10%;
      left: 60%;
      top: 30%;
      bottom: 30%;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: none;
     }
.carousel-indicators{
      font-size: 2em;
      bottom: -1%;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: none;
        }

/***
 * Bootstrap relies on CSS transitions for animation, which makes it
 * easy to override.  Just add the vertical class to your carousel:
 * <div class='carousel vertical'>...</div>
 ***/

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel.vertical .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -moz-transition:    0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -ms-transition:     0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition:      0.6s ease-in-out top;
  left:               0;
}
.carousel.vertical .active,
.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right    { top:     0; }
.carousel.vertical .next,
.carousel.vertical .active.right  { top:  100%; }
.carousel.vertical .prev,
.carousel.vertical .active.left   { top: -100%; }        
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap Vertical carousel demo</h1>
<!--The main div for carousel-->
<div id="carousel-demo" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
 <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-demo" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Sliding images statring here --> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <div class="item active"> 
      <img src="images/banana.jpg" alt="banana"> 
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>The Banana slide</h3>
       <p>Banana is useful for health</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="item"> 
      <img src="images/currant.jpg" alt="currant"> 
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>The currant slide</h3>
       <p>Text here</p>
      </div>      
   </div> 
    <div class="item"> 
      <img src="images/mango.jpg" alt="mango"> 
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>The Mangos</h3>
       <p>Text here</p>
      </div>          
    </div>
    <div class="item"> 
      <img src="images/strawberries.jpg" alt="strawberries">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>The strawberries</h3>
       <p>Text here</p>
      </div>           
    </div> 

  </div> 

  <!-- Next / Previous controls here -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>

 <div>

 </div> 
  </div>


</div>
```

When i tried to bind to a database using a repeater control, slider is not showing..

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    color: #515151;
}
img {
     width: 40%;
    }

.carousel-inner {
}

.carousel-caption {
      font-size: 2em;
      right: 10%;
      left: 60%;
      top: 30%;
      bottom: 30%;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: none;
     }
.carousel-indicators{
      font-size: 2em;
      bottom: -1%;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: none;
        }

/***
 * Bootstrap relies on CSS transitions for animation, which makes it
 * easy to override.  Just add the vertical class to your carousel:
 * <div class='carousel vertical'>...</div>
 ***/

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel.vertical .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -moz-transition:    0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -ms-transition:     0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition:      0.6s ease-in-out top;
  left:               0;
}
.carousel.vertical .active,
.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right    { top:     0; }
.carousel.vertical .next,
.carousel.vertical .active.right  { top:  100%; }
.carousel.vertical .prev,
.carousel.vertical .active.left   { top: -100%; }        
</style>
 <div class="container">
                  <h1>Bootstrap Vertical carousel demo</h1>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>


                  <div id="carousel-demo" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
                        <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                         <div class="item"> 
       <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Value") %>' title='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text").ToString()).Split('.')[0].ToString() %>' style="margin-top:500px;" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption"style="padding-top:500px;">
       <h3>The currant slide</h3>
       <p>Text here</p>
      </div>      
   </div>
</div>


                        </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>

                             </div>


  <!-- Next / Previous controls here -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>

 <div>

 </div> 
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: your provided code doesn't have any repeater, we need to see that to know the problem.

Comment: How you want to make it dynamic. do you want to pull data from database. if so then you can add it by binding it with database using repeater control.

Comment: I did that.. but slider pictures are not scrolling.. first picture is always showing.